Does a group action of a semisimple ring preserve semisimpleness?
I am trying to prove a Lemma (2.1.2) from the paper of [BGS96] on Koszul Duality.
The Lemma states that if we have A, a positively graded ring with $A_{0}$ semisimple and two graded A-modules M,N concentrated in degrees m, resp. n, then $ext^{i}_{A}(M,N)=0 \forall i>n-m$.
I´ve already concluded that is sufices to show that there exists a P free graded A-module with $P \twoheadrightarrow M $ with an isomorphism in degree m.
I have gotten the hint to look at the s.e.s
$ 0 \rightarrow M_{>n} \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/M_{>n} \rightarrow 0 $
which implies that there is a group action from k onto $M/M_{>m}$.
Here comes my question: does this imply that $M/M_{>m} \cong \bigoplus _{i \in I} k$?
Because if this is true then there we can see that there is a free module projecting onto $M/M_{>m}$ and I think also onto $M_{>m}$ so that the summand of those two free modules is our P.
Am I on the right path? Thanks for any input :)

Please tell us which paper [BGS96] is (title, doi, authors?).

It's Koszul duality patterns in representation theory by Beilinson-Ginzburg-Soergel (https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-02/S0894-0347-96-00192-0/S0894-0347-96-00192-0.pdf).

Yes, exactly :)
